# How to open and close tableView on a button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uibutton

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnR3O.png)I'm working on dropDowns, i'm creating buttons and dropdown tableView dynamically. When i click first button last tableView was opened. But i want to open specific tableView (at a time i want to open only one dropdown).

```
float y = 0;
    float x = (self.answersView.frame.size.width/2)+175;

    float Iy = 0;
    float Ix = 675;

    float Tx = (self.answersView.frame.size.width/2)+175;
    float Ty = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<self.radioBtnTagArr.count; i++) {

        self.dropdownBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        self.dropdownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x, y+30, (self.answersView.frame.size.width/2)-200, 50);
        [self.dropdownBtn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.dropdownBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [self.dropdownBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:24/255.0 green:56/255.0 blue:131/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.dropdownBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];

        [self.dropdownBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dropdownBtnTapMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.dropdownBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.dropdownBtn];
        self.dropdownBtn.tag = [[self.btnTagArr objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        y = y+70;

        self.dropdownImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Ix, Iy+50, 20, 10)];
        self.dropdownImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown.png"];
        [self.answersView addSubview:self.dropdownImageView];

        Iy = Iy+70;

        self.dropdownTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Tx, Ty+80, (self.answersView.frame.size.width/2)-200, 50) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.content = @[ @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",@"Sunday"];
        self.dropdownTableView.delegate = self;
        self.dropdownTableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.answersView addSubview:self.dropdownTableView];

        Ty = Ty+70;

        self.dropdownTableView.hidden = YES;

    }
```

//The event handling method

```
- (void)dropdownBtnTapMethod:(UIButton *) sender {


            if (self.dropdownTableView.hidden == YES) {
                self.dropdownTableView.hidden = NO;
            } else {
                self.dropdownTableView.hidden = YES;
            }

}
```

And how to set table view height dynamically.

Comment: can you share screenshot for expected view's ?

Comment: what is answersView and what does this view ?

Comment: answersView is one subView in mainView. And it has scrollView also.

Comment: you can make this view using tableview. name and image add as section . on click of section you can hide and show rows.

Comment: When I click first btn I want to open first table only, and when I click first btn again I want to close it. like this i want for all buns...

Comment: I know how to open and close, but the broblem is when I click first btn last btn tableView was opend.

Comment: yes it will be open last tableview because there are only last tableview reference exist. so when you clicked on button so it will open last tableview only . also same problem will occurs for all buttons.

Comment: Can u provide any solution for me...

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray *arrTableview; // make global
```

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
  arrTableview = [NSMutableArray New];
```

**Change in following method**

```
for (int i=0; i<self.radioBtnTagArr.count; i++) {

        self.dropdownBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        self.dropdownBtn.tag = i; // add this line
        self.dropdownBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x, y+30, (self.answersView.frame.size.width/2)-200, 50);
        [self.dropdownBtn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.dropdownBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        [self.dropdownBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:24/255.0 green:56/255.0 blue:131/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.dropdownBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];

        [self.dropdownBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dropdownBtnTapMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.dropdownBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.dropdownBtn];
        //self.dropdownBtn.tag = [[self.btnTagArr objectAtIndex:i] intValue]; // This line commented.

        y = y+70;

        self.dropdownImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Ix, Iy+50, 20, 10)];
        self.dropdownImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown.png"];
        [self.answersView addSubview:self.dropdownImageView];

        Iy = Iy+70;

        self.dropdownTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Tx, Ty+80, (self.answersView.frame.size.width/2)-200, 50) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        self.content = @[ @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",@"Sunday"];
        self.dropdownTableView.delegate = self;
        self.dropdownTableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.answersView addSubview:self.dropdownTableView];
        [arrTableview addObject :self.dropdownTableView]; 
        Ty = Ty+70;

        self.dropdownTableView.hidden = YES;

    }
```

**Selector**

```
- (void)dropdownBtnTapMethod:(UIButton *) sender {
     UITableView *tableView =[arrTableview objectAtIndex:sender.tag]

            if (tableView.hidden == YES) {
                tableView.hidden = NO;
            } else {
                tableView.hidden = YES;
            }

}
```

Comment: UITableView *tableView =[arrTableview objectAtIndexPath:sender.tag] Here you are asking sender.tag into arrTableView, but I am getting no visible interface objectAtIndexPath:

Comment: any issue with this?

Comment: I am getting error no visible interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectAtIndexPath:'

Comment: i have update answer. check you need to take tableview's reference from array.

Comment: I removed path form objectAtInedxPath: ,  I added like this...UITableView *tableView = [self.arrTableview objectAtIndex:sender.tag];  But I am getting exception. Exception is.. index 90 beyond bounds for empty array.

Comment: I am assigning dynamic tags which are comes from server.

Comment: did you add this line : self.dropdownBtn.tag = i

Comment: yes, i  added, but i'm getting NSRangeException. index 90 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: can you check arrTableview and radioBtnTagArr count is same or not ?

Comment: it will best solution for this scenario you need to debug your code and correct some issue .

Comment: I'm getting arrTableView = null why?

Comment: objects not added to arrTableView

Comment: i have already mentioned in my answer         [arrTableview addObject :self.dropdownTableView];

Comment: yes, ok I changed this line above for loop self.arrTableview = [NSMutableArray new]; from view did load, now tableViews added

Comment: I'm getting exception index 90 beyond bounds [0... 4]

Comment: can you check arrTableview and radioBtnTagArr count is same or not ?

Comment: then check sender tag value also . it should be smaller than count of array.

Comment: we are creating tableViews based on radioBtnTagArr count.

Comment: yes, that's the problem, sending value is 90, arrTableView count is 5

Comment: ok then check tag value and ensure that your have only assign value while i have mentioned in answer.

Comment: and also check if you click on first button then sender value should be zero.

Comment: self.dropdownBtn.tag = I; I am commenting second  this line  // self.dropdownBtn.tag = [[self.radioBtnTagArr objectAtIndex:i] intValue]; Now it's working...Thank u...

Comment: Welcome.It is my pleasure to help you.